# Am I computing these summations the right way?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

Given Algorithm:

```
 for i = 1, 2, . . . , n  
     for j = i + 1, i + 2, . . . , n
         Add up array entries A[i] through A[j]
         Store the result in B[i, j]
    Endfor
 Endfor
```

My attempt:
Solving for worst case using Big-O notation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n}n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}n(n-i) = \frac{n^{3}}{2}-\frac{n^{2}}{2}$$ Therefore for the worst case running time we have: $$O(n^3)$$
Is that correct? Or did I not interpreted the algorithm correctly.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
B(i,j)= \sum_{k=i}^{j} A(k)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Yeah it will have a run time that is order $n^3$.

Comment: worst case, first loop is linear, so is 2nd loop, so is the addition inside - hence $n \cdot n \cdot n = n^3$...

Comment: Ah I see, thanks.